# Melee vs Brawling feasibility

Tags: wasteland-3

Many older Wasteland 3 guides recommend brawling builds. The reason is simple - 10 points in the Brawling skill gives you access to the "Flurry of Blows" perk

[image]

Since for most brawling weapons, an attack costs typically 2 AP, with this perk you can do attacks with only 1 AP! That gives you ~8-12 attacks per round including 1-3 strike attacks!
The drawback is in theory the low number of brawling weapons, but in practice, you can get access to Power Gauntlet relatively quickly.

But then if you look at more recent build guides, (like [this one](https://www.thegamer.com/wasteland-3-best-builds/) or [this](https://fextralife.com/wasteland-3-builds-drunk-fu-fighter/)), seem to point to melee as better than brawling. "The Gamer" actually says that melee is **the best** possible build. Indeed, there are more melee weapons than brawling ones, but I can't see that the former are that much better, especially if we use the previously mentioned Flurry of Blows

Am I missing something? Is melee indeed better with the right perks?